# Scrolling on single line code snipets

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I realise this will be a bit of a pain to solve, but when trying to read long, one line code snippets, I find myself having to constantly stop to read what I've scrolled to, as showing here:

> [image]

I know this is most likely only an issue on certain OSs (I'm on OSX with a "Magic Mouse"), but it's really frustrating. I realise there's about a 10px space at the top of that line that you can use to scroll, but sometimes jumping in and out of that sweet spot isn't as easy as it sounds with a sensitive mouse.

Comment: Agree, this is really annoying. You could in OSX set the scrollbar as always visible, but this is ugly. I like this tiny little "autoshow scrollbar" thing in Aqua.

Comment: Came here to ask about the same thing. Wonder what the plans are to fix it. It's really really annoying

Comment: I have the same issue and its blatantly annoying, `macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54)` + `Chrome 71.0.3578.98`

Comment: @Connor probably nothing; browsers have decided to let Mac's OS styling override their own.

Comment: Yeah, this is really annoying. My env also: `macOS Mojave 10.14.3 Beta (18D39a)` + `Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. Feels like it's been this way for the past couple months, actually.